# Database candidate keys from functional dependencies - specific technicality

Tags: database, functional-dependencies, candidate-key

I am working with a relational database's set of attributes and set of functional dependencies and have a specific question about which keys would be considered candidate keys of this schema.

The set of attributes I am working with is:

```
R = (A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H)
```

And the set of functional dependencies are:

```
F = { AC -> B, AB -> C, AD -> E, C -> D, BC -> A, E -> G, ABE -> D, FG -> E}
```

So here's what I am trying to figure out: Would this set of attributes have *any* candidate keys since H is not determined/mentioned at all in the set of functional dependencies?

By definition, candidate keys determine everything else, correct? If H is not determined by anything but itself, would there still be any candidate keys in this set?

Any insight is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is R a relation schema or just a set of attributes? If R is a relation then {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H} must be a superkey and therefore R has at least one candidate key.

Answer (score 1):

Recall ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candidate_key)) that

> In the relational model of databases, a candidate key of a relation is
>   a minimal superkey for that relation; that is, a set of attributes
>   such that the relation does not have two distinct tuples (i.e. rows or
>   records in common database language) with the same values for these
>   attributes (which means that the set of attributes is a superkey)
>   there is no proper subset of these attributes for which (1) holds
>   (which means that the set is minimal).

Hence,

> So here's what I am trying to figure out: Would this set of attributes have any candidate keys since H is not determined/mentioned at all in the set of functional dependencies?

This simply means that H will be contained in *every* candidate key R might have. For instance, ACFH is a candidate key. You can infer B because of AC->B, D because of C->D, E because of AD->E, and G because of E->G. On the other hand, you cannot infer F from ACH, H from ACF, C from AFH and A from CFH.